# Partial update repeater QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm facing a little issue with QML/C++ project. I'm using a repeater to draw points inside a Rectangle and those points come from a model. Here is my code :

main.qml

```
Rectangle { 
      id: rect
      height:500
      width:500
      Repeater {
          id: pointsRepeater
          model: qListPoints
          Point {
          }
      }
}
```

qListPoints come from my C++ where I wrote :
`Q_PROPERTY( QVariant qListPoints READ getListPoints NOTIFY listPointsChanged)`

So basically when I add or update a list point I emit listPointsChanged() and my main.qml redraw new or updated points from the list. My issue is when I add points to my list and I emit listPointsChanged() all points are redrawn, It's like a slow strobe effect. I want only the new point either redraw. Is it possible ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does qListPoints contain?

Comment: It containt QList<QObject *> where QObjects are from my Point class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that if you used a proper model derived from [QAbstractListModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html), for example, then only the points that you add/change/remove will be redrawn. The problem that you're seeing is likely the same as the one mentioned [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qobjectlist-based-model):

> Note: There is no way for the view to know that the contents of a QList has changed. If the QList changes, it is necessary to reset the model by calling QQmlContext::setContextProperty() again.

The view only knows that the property has changed, but it doesn't know anything about specific items in that model, so it just redraws everything.

[Using C++ Models with Qt Quick Views](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html) has more information about this.

Comment: How will I access my point class attributes from the  Point.qml file load in the  repeater with QAbstractListModel. Currently I use modelData.posX for exemple, will it work with QAbstractListModel ?

Comment: You should be able to access the properties via the role names that you define in your C++ model: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#models

Comment: Ok  thanks dude. I will look at  QAbstractListModel. Keep you in touch . Thanks for your time